# D3 dispatch pass in arguments and calling context

Tags: javascript, oop, d3.js, prototype

I understand that in D3, dispatch can be used to fire events to multiple visualisations according to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848).

I also understand that if I want to call a dispatch from an object and pass in the context, I can use `apply` as shown [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#dispatch).

However, I'm having a hard time combining the arguments from a D3 dispatch and the context that I want.

```js
// create my dispatcher
var probeDispatch = d3.dispatch("probeLoad");
var line_count = 0;

// load a file with a bunch of JSON and send one entry every 50 ms
var lines = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]];
var parse_timer = window.setInterval(
    function () {
        parse_dispatch();
    }, 50
);

function parse_dispatch(){
  // send two arguments with my dispatch
  probeDispatch.probeLoad(lines[line_count][0], lines[line_count][1]);
  line_count += 1;
  if(line_count >= lines.length){
    //line_count = 0
    window.clearInterval(parse_timer);
  }
}

// my chart object
var genChart = function(label){
  this.label = label;
  // assume I've drawn my chart somewhere here
  probeDispatch.on(("probeLoad."+this.label), this.probeParse);
  // this next line isn't working, since the
  // console.log in probeLoad still returns undefined
  probeDispatch.probeLoad.apply(this);
};

genChart.prototype = {
    probeParse: function(probeData, simTime) {

      // How do I get the context from the object that's calling probeParse
      // into the probeParse scope?
      var self = this;
      console.log(self.label);
    }
};

new genChart("pants");
new genChart("shirt");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out to bring the context into the function, I have to `bind()` it for reasons I'm not too clear on.

```js
// create my dispatcher
var probeDispatch = d3.dispatch("probeLoad");
var line_count = 0;

// load a file with a bunch of JSON and send one entry every 50 ms
var lines = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]];
var parse_timer = window.setInterval(
    function () {
        parse_dispatch();
    }, 50
);

function parse_dispatch(){
  // send two arguments with my dispatch
  probeDispatch.probeLoad(lines[line_count][0], lines[line_count][1]);
  line_count += 1;
  if(line_count >= lines.length){
    //line_count = 0
    window.clearInterval(parse_timer);
  }
}

// my chart object
var genChart = function(label){
  this.label = label;
  // assume I've drawn my chart somewhere here
  probeDispatch.on(("probeLoad."+this.label), this.probeParse.bind(this));
};

genChart.prototype = {
    probeParse: function(probeData, simTime) {

      // How do I get the context from the object that's calling probeParse
      // into the probeParse scope?
      var self = this;
      console.log(self.label);
    }
};

new genChart("pants");
new genChart("shirt");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

#### Added by meetamit

Bind is the solution here, because it locks a scope to an "instance" of `genChart.prototype. probeParse`. This way `parse_dispatch` (the invoker) doesn't need to know anything about scope. It's equivalent to this:

```
// my chart object
var genChart = function(label){
  this.label = label;
  var self = this;
  var probeParseBound = function() { self.probeParse(); };
  probeDispatch.on(("probeLoad."+this.label), probeParseBound);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It *does* set the context properly when you see `"pants"` in the console.

But then there are 3 undefined's logged, because you also call

```
  // send two arguments with my dispatch
  probeDispatch.probeLoad(lines[line_count][0], lines[line_count][1]);
```

without supplying context.

You need

```
probeDispatch.probeLoad.apply(instanceOfGenChart, [lines[line_count][0], lines[line_count][1]]);
```

But enabling that also requires moveing `parse_dispatch` down the page.

```js
// create my dispatcher
var probeDispatch = d3.dispatch("probeLoad");
var line_count = 0;

// load a file with a bunch of JSON and send one entry every 50 ms
var lines = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]];
var parse_timer = window.setInterval(
    function () {
        parse_dispatch();
    }, 50
);

// my chart object
var genChart = function(label){
  this.label = label;
  // assume I've drawn my chart somewhere here
  probeDispatch.on(("probeLoad."+this.label), this.probeParse);
  // this next line isn't working, but I don't know what to do
  probeDispatch.probeLoad.apply(this);
};

genChart.prototype = {
    probeParse: function(probeData, simTime) {

      // How do I get the context from the object that's calling probeParse
      // into the probeParse scope?
      var self = this;
      console.log(self.label);
    }
};

var instanceOfGenChart = new genChart("pants");

function parse_dispatch(){
  // send two arguments with my dispatch
  probeDispatch.probeLoad.apply(instanceOfGenChart, [lines[line_count][0], lines[line_count][1]]);
  line_count += 1;
  if(line_count >= lines.length){
    //line_count = 0
    window.clearInterval(parse_timer);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it turns out I asked the wrong question. I've edited it now (to include the fact that I was thinking of using the same dispatch from multiple charts) and I'm hoping I can piece it together from here and if I do, I'll mark it as correct. Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Comment: @Seanny123 No worries. I added some stuff about `bind` to your answer.